# Signalr: how does receiving messages from PersistentConnection work internally?

Tags: signalr

I wonder how does SignalR client receive messages from server after connection has been established? I mean, what happens on the client side internally after `Connection.Send(message)` method has been invoked?

From reading .NET client code I've found that `public event Action<string> Received` in `Connection` class is responsible for receiving messages, but I can't find how it is implemented. I need to know how it works internally because I want to write my own client on Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the entire source of signalR on github: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

In particular, you can find the source for PersistentConnection - at 
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/PersistentConnection.cs